# Why date is getting interpreted wrongly in this case

Tags: java

I have got a group of rss feeds and i used rssmix to group them together .

I am facing  issues with date , the date is being mismatched with the actual news provider and the date obtained through rssmix

The date provided by the actual news provider is

**Jan 13, 2016, 09.12 AM**

Where as through rssmix i am getting this date

**2016-01-13 02:30**

I have used all the date conversions , please see this is my complete program

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Test {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);
    private static Test instance = null;
    private static DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    private static final long DAY = 43200000;

    // private static final long DAY = 30400000;

    public Test() {
    }

    public static Test getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Test();
        return instance;
    }

    public static DocumentBuilder getDocumentBuilderInstance()
            throws ParserConfigurationException {
        if (builder == null)
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        return builder;
    }

    private static SimpleDateFormat in_newsupdater = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "E,dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    private static SimpleDateFormat out_newsupdater = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            final JSONArray latestnews = new JSONArray();
            builder = getDocumentBuilderInstance();
            final URL url = new URL("http://www.rssmix.com/u/8171434/rss.xml");
            final Document doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
            final NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                final JSONObject jsonobj_allnews = new JSONObject();
                final Element item = (Element) items.item(i);
                String title = getValue(item, "title");

                String link = getValue(item, "link");
                String pub_date = getValue(item, "pubDate");

                System.out.println("recievied" + pub_date);

                pub_date = convertdate(pub_date);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public static String convertdate(final String recivieddate)
            throws ParseException {

        Date date = in_newsupdater.parse(recivieddate);
        in_newsupdater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        out_newsupdater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
        return out_newsupdater.format(date);
    }

    public static String getValue(final Element parent, final String nodeName) {
        return parent.getElementsByTagName(nodeName).item(0).getFirstChild()
                .getNodeValue();
    }

}
```

Could you please let me know how to fix this issue .

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong ,I m getting output as 2016-01-13 02:30 , but where as it should be 2016-01-13 09:12 know (Hours and minutes correctly)

Comment: This doesn't look at all like any time zone or locale issue which comes to mind.  Is it possible that there is a lag between your original published time and the time when you read the timestamp from the server?  This might explain the discrepancy.

Comment: In my linux server , when i checked time it shows correct IST time . m below is the output from my server which is correct

Comment: date
Wed Jan 13 10:23:51 IST 2016
zambier@s97-74-xxx-xxx [~]#

Answer (score 0):

You want the time in GMT(UTC) to be converted to to Asia/Kolkata right. The time difference is +5.30 hours. So `Wed, 13 Jan 2016 02:30:22 +0000` will be `2016-01-13 08:00`

```
    SimpleDateFormat in_newsupdater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    SimpleDateFormat out_newsupdater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    Date date = in_newsupdater.parse("Wed, 13 Jan 2016 02:30:22 +0000");
    out_newsupdater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    System.out.println( out_newsupdater.format(date));
```

Comment: Sorry if i confused you, the actual data given by rss provider is Wed, 13 Jan 2016 02:30:22 +0000 and i cannot use directly Jan 13, 2016, 09.12 AM  (Example SGX Nifty indicates a positive start; IIP, TCS disappoints Wed, 13 Jan 2016 02:30:22 +0000)

Comment: so 'Wed, 13 Jan 2016 02:30:22 +0000' should be converted to '2016-01-13 09:12' ?